# Combining all sheets in a workbook except for one

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook that has many sheets with different names that need to be combined together into one sheet. I found this code which works great, except I need it to ignore a sheet called "COMMAND" (which is used for other purposes). The code currently will create a sheet called "Combined" and will combine all sheets to it, but I would prefer it if the Combine sheet doesn't need to be created and deleted each time. So to clarify, all sheets in this workbook needs to be combined to the "Combined" sheet except the sheet called "COMMAND".

```
Private Sub COMBINE()
Dim J As Integer
On Error Resume Next
Sheets(1).Select
Worksheets.Add
Sheets(1).Name = "Combined"
Sheets(2).Activate
Range("A1").EntireRow.Select
Selection.Copy Destination:=Sheets(1).Range("A1")
For J = 2 To Sheets.Count
Sheets(J).Activate
Range("A1").Select
Selection.CurrentRegion.Select
Selection.Offset(1, 0).Resize(Selection.Rows.Count - 1).Select
Selection.Copy Destination:=Sheets(1).Range("A65536").End(xlUp)(2)
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Note: `.Range("A65536").End(xlUp)` worked fine in Excel 2003, but these days a worksheet might have hundreds of thousands of rows - `.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xUp)` would be safer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet, wsCombined As Worksheet
    Dim SheetName As String
    Dim SheetExists As Boolean

    SheetName = "Combined"
    SheetExists = False

    With ThisWorkbook
        'Check if the Sheet exists
        For Each ws In .Worksheets

            If ws.Name = SheetName Then
                SheetExists = True
                Exit For
            End If

        Next

        If SheetExists = False Then
            'If the sheet dont exists, create
            .Sheets.Add(After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)).Name = SheetName
        End If

        Set wsCombined = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Combined")

        For Each ws In .Worksheets

            If ws.Name <> "COMMAND" And ws.Name <> "Combined" Then

                LastRow = wsCombined.Cells(wsCombined.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

                ws.UsedRange.Copy wsCombined.Range("A" & LastRow + 1)

            End If

        Next

    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of Sheets(1).Select, you can use the below code and change the sheet name to the sheet  name  on your 1st workbook.

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Copy